# Confused by paragraph in Conway's book "Functions of one complex variable".

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Cauchy's theorem (see 5.7 in Conway's book, p85) tells us the following:

Let $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open subset and $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ an analytic function. If $\gamma$ is a closed rectifiable curve in $G$ such that $n(\gamma,w) = 0$ for all $w\in \mathbb{C}-G$, then
$$\oint_\gamma f = 0.$$

Consider now the following paragraph in Conway's book:

[image]

How is the sentence $\int_\gamma f = 0$ for all closed curves $\gamma$ true, if $f$ is analytic?

For example, consider $G= \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. Consider $\gamma(t) = \exp(2\pi it), 0 \le t \le 1$. Then the function $z\mapsto z^{-1}$ is analytic on $G$, $\gamma$ is a closed surve in $G$ and
$$\oint_\gamma z^{-1} dz = \int_0^1 \frac{2\pi i \exp(2\pi i t)}{\exp(2\pi it)}dt = 2\pi i\ne 0.$$
What am I missing here?

Comment: What does the notatio;n $n(\gamma,w)$ mean?

Comment: @bof $n(\gamma,w) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma (z-w)^{-1}dz \in \mathbb{Z}$ for $w\notin \{\gamma\}$, the winding number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To re-emphasise the point about $\int_{\gamma}f=0$.

If $f$ is analytic on a domain - an open simply connected set - all integrals of $f$ around a closed contour are zero. Without simple connectivity you allow for singularities to hide in the “holes” of the set, and it may be that the function has nonzero residues hence a nonzero integral around certain closed contours.

$G$ is not a region, in the sense I assume Conway defines (open, simply connected). It does not have simple connectivity due to the “hole” at zero: simple connectivity is important in the proofs of the Cauchy theorems.

The presence, and effect, of the ‘hole’ is touching on the residue theorem. $2\pi i=2\pi i\cdot(1)$ and $(1)$ is the residue of $z\mapsto z^{-1}$ at $0$.

Comment: On p40, Conway defines a region to be an open and connected subset of the plane. Simple connectivity is only introduced in the section after Morera's theorem.

Comment: I don't think the proof of Morera's theorem requires simple connectivity of the domain. The other statements concerning Cauchy's theorems in Conway don't even mention any connectedness assumptions.

Comment: @Andromeda But, as your example shows, these connectivity hypotheses are essential. I didn’t say Morera’s theorem requires simple connectivity either; your “counterexample” did not (as bof says) meet the Morera hypotheses. For Cauchy’s theorem - integral on a closed contour is zero - you absolutely need a simply connected set.

Comment: @Andromeda *Locally*, any open set is simply connected since open discs are simply connected. That might be why Conway has not yet mentioned it. But if you want to prove Cauchy’s integral theorem - really, *homotopy invariance* of contour integrals of analytic functions - you need to actually be able to apply homotopies of curves. In this context that necessitates a simply connected domain. Another example: since $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is not simply connected, the analytic function $e^{1/z}$ doesn’t necessarily (and doesn’t) integrate to zero around the unit circle.

Comment: Thanks! I think it's starting to make sense. Conway was just a bit sloppy with the connectivity assumptions :)

Comment: Another (related) question, which triggered this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524635/is-this-solution-flawed-uniform-limit-of-analytic-functions-is-analytic

Comment: Now that I think about it: In Conway's formulation of Morera's theorem, he asks that $G$ is open and connected. However, we can leave out the connectedness assumption because it suffices to show that $f$ is analytic on each open ball contained in $G$, right?

Comment: @Andromeda If the domain is not connected then you could have triangular “contours” with significant jumps (visual discontinuities that aren’t discontinuous due to the gap in the domain) that the majority of functions wouldn’t integrate to zero around. Connected domain makes the hypotheses much more natural and likely to be satisfied.

Comment: I know, but still I don't see what's wrong with the following reasoning: say Morera's theorem has been established for connected open subsets. Then, let $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open and satisfy the condition $\int_T f= 0$ for all triangular paths in $G$. Let $a\in G$. Choose $R > 0$ with $B(a,R)\subseteq G$. Then also $\int_T f = 0$ for all triangular paths $T\subseteq B(a,R)$. Hence, since $B(a,R)$ is connected, Morera's theorem implies that $f$ is analytic on $B(a,R)$. Since $a$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f$ is analytic. Hence, we do not need the connectedness assumption.

Comment: Do I miss something here? (Also, I will put a bounty on this question for all the help you are giving me, whenever I can).

Comment: @Andromeda Morera’s theorem still works, I am pretty sure, on disconnected sets. It’s just that the hypotheses are much more unlikely to be satisfied - it’s more convenient to state and prove it on a connected domain. If you have a disconnected domain then Morera’s theorem is most usefully applied individually per connected component (because there hypotheses are easier to satisfy) and at this point you’ve reduced to the connected case anyway…

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Thanks!